# Confused about complexity of counting sort algorithm

Tags: c, counting-sort

I have two doubts about the counting sort algorithm:

1. How is the complexity only `O(n)`? There are 5 for loops in the algorithm. Should the complexity for each for loop be n? So result in `n^4` complexity? I know I am wrong and counting sort is linear, but I want to know why my reasoning is wrong.
2. If the counting sort algorithm is linear, why is it `O(n+K)` and not just `O(n)`, if the `K` is added it is not linear anymore right?

This is the counting sort code I am referring too:

```
void countSort(char *str)
{
    // The output character array that will have sorted str
    char output[strlen(str)];

    // Create a count array to store count of inidividul characters and
    // initialize count array as 0
    int count[RANGE + 1], i;
    memset(count, 0, sizeof(count));

    // Store count of each character
    for(i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
        ++count[str[i]];

    // Change count[i] so that count[i] now contains actual position of
    // this character in output array
    for (i = 1; i <= RANGE; ++i)
        count[i] += count[i-1];

    // Build the output character array
    for (i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    {
        output[count[str[i]]-1] = str[i];
        --count[str[i]];
    }

    // Copy the output array to str, so that str now
    // contains sorted characters
    for (i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
        str[i] = output[i];
}
```

Comment: The loops are not nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer 1:

Let there be three 'for' loops that each works in `O(n)`
therefore the overall complexity is of:

`O(n)+O(n)+O(n) = O(n+n+n) = O(3n)`

in the case of `3n`, the `3` is a constant and can be ignored and thus the complexity diminishes to `O(n)`

To answer 2:

the algorithm depends not only on the size `N` of the array, but also on the range `K` of the numbers collected in it. it would require a larger counting array and thus iterations to count sort the array:

`{1,10000000,3,2,0} // K=10000001`

than it would:

`{1,4,5,2,3} // K=6`

therefore the complexity the for loops used your code are calculated this way:

```
for(i = 0; str[i]; ++i) // O(n)

for (i = 1; i <= RANGE; ++i) // O(k)

for (i = 0; str[i]; ++i) // O(n)

for (i = 0; str[i]; ++i) // O(n)
```

and the overall complexity is that of `O(n)+O(n)+O(n)+O(k) = O(n+k)` and to pinpoint my answer to your question: the algorithm complexity is still viewed as linear.

Comment: @martinkunev I chose to ignore the `memset()` function because it's not part of the algorithm but a part of the implementation in C. also it takes `RANGE+1` as it's size argument and thus will calculate to `O(k)`.

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotic complexity shows in some sense the number of operations as a function of the size of the input. This is useful because it shows how much an algorithm slows down as the size of the input grows. Constants don't impact the slowdown so they are ignored. Ignoring the constants we get:

`strlen(str)` does `strlen(str)` number of operations (it examines the whole string until it finds `'\0'`)
`memset()` does `strlen(str)` number of operations
the second `for` does `RANGE` number of operations
each one of the other three `for`s does `strlen(str)` number of operations

In your example `strlen(str)` is denoted with `n` and `RANGE` with `K`. So the whole function does `O(5n + K) = O(n + K)` operations.

`n + K` is still a linear function, be it of two variables (it's a polynomial of power 1).

To get a deeper understanding of this, you'll need to read some more about asymptotic complexity (the rigorous mathematical theory).